# Scikitlearn: testing using other dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm currently using scikitlearn on one dataset (I'll refer to as `dataset 1`) and it's providing me with some freakishly accurate results across multiple classifiers (I believe I've tested around 8, with the lowest accuracy being 88% and the highest being around 98%). Because of these extremely high accuracies I suspect there to be a bias in the dataset I'm using. I want to try and test my existing models on another dataset (I'll refer to as `dataset 2` of the same theme, as well as data I collect from websites myself (I'll do this later though), however when trying to pass in the new dataset to predict I'm encountering a few issues.

My first question is, should I be using the existing Tdfvectorizer that I used for `dataset 1` on my new dataset or should I create a separate Tdfvectorizer object?

At the moment I'm currently just trying to predict a few samples of the dataset but I'm encountering an error where the features are different sizes:
`ValueError: X has 194439 features, but ExtraTreesClassifier is expecting 251681 features as input.`
Is there some sort of function within scikitlearn where I can compactify the existing features the model has been trained on to be the same size as the new dataset (`dataset 2`)?.

I also tried doing a further `train_test_split` on my new `dataset 2` and pass these off into the `accuracy_score` functions scikitlearn provides but I was again met with the above error regarding feature input sizes.

Am I approaching this with the wrong methodology or is my execution just poor somewhere?

I am happy to provide some snippets where needed.

Thanks

Comment: You always have to think like this: what would you do if you want to evaluate one sample?. Then, about your first question of tdfvectorizer: Keep the one trained. Second, of course, to evaluate samples, they have to have the same dimension/shape of the trained one. How to achieve that? Just make exactly the same transformation you did when training the model (tdfvectorizer, encoding,...)

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat Thank you for your reply. I have, to my knowledge, applied to same preprocessing to both datasets. They both consist of a body of text essentially, so I've removed punctuation, lowercase, removed stopwords etc. for both the sets. Is it not working because the datasets don't have the same number of unique words (in this case each unique word would be a feature)?

Comment: These are a lot of design questions, SO is for programming questions so it would be better to ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Very short answer: accuracy is probably the wrong performance measure, except if your classes are balanced; you should check for overfitting, because you likely have way too many features; you should remove the rare words (use `min_df`); and you must use the vocabulary encoded on the training data when you apply on the test set.